# Conda install vs pip install(issues in importing seaborn package)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, python-import

I am facing an issue in importing module in jupyter notebook. The issue is that I access the jupyter notebook through anaconda software and when i tired installing seaborn, I used the command "pip install seaborn" in cmd and the package was installed(verifed through "pip list") but when i tried importing the seborn package in notebook it gave the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seaborn'` I even restarted the kernel,notebook and anacond but still the issue persisted. But when i did "conda list" in the notebook the package was not there but then after "conda install seaborn" the package got installed and the package got imported. I wanted to know why this error occured as i didnt face this situation while importing numpy or pandas(for numpy or pandas only pip install was enough)

python version:3.10.5

conda version:4.14.0

jupyter version:4.10.0

Comment: have you tried `!pip install seaborn` in a jupyter notebook cell?

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: Without more information (such as OP's command history and environment settings), one can't answer this question with 100% confidence, but there is a most likely explanation:

Running `pip install seaborn` via cmd installed `seaborn` in a directory that is not part of the Python path of the conda environment that the Jupyter Notebook was running in. It seems most likely you were not using a conda command prompt to `pip install seaborn`, but you were using a conda command prompt to `pip install` `numpy` and `pandas`, which is why they were installed in a directory included in the Jupyter Notebook's conda environment's Python path.

For example, a standard conda package install location in a Windows-style filesystem for a conda environment named `<env-name>` is the `site-packages` directory for that environment, `C:\Users\<User>\<Conda_Distribution>\envs\<env-name>\Lib\site-packages`. This directory is in the Python path of a its corresponding environment by default.

This knowledge of where to find your actual conda packages in a directory comes with a warning: **Unless you have expert knowledge of the Python import system and conda's package management infrastructure, it is a generally a bad idea to manually add or delete directories in your conda environment's `site-packages` directory.**

A related warning: Although the interoperability of pip with conda has been greatly improved in the last few years, **it is generally a bad idea to use pip to install standard Python packages in your conda environment.** [`conda install`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html) exists, and [you should use it for a reason](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment).

For more detailed information about what your Python path is and how it's set, see [this informational guide](https://realpython.com/python-import/#pythons-import-path) from Real Python.

Comment: Thanks for the answer as said used conda install in anaconda environment and it worked